# Can we attach one IAM role to more than one user in EKS?

Tags: amazon-eks

I want to modify aws-auth.yaml and add one Kubernetes user under mapRole section. I wonder if I can attach multiple EKS user to the same IAM role for authentication. Will that work ?

Comment: what do you mean by EKS user ? did you mean map one IAM to multiple K8 user/groups ?

Comment: @prasun Yes, That's what I meant.

Comment: Although, I have not tried that, but, I doubt that will work as Kubernetes needs to know one user/group for which it will authenticate against RBAC for kubernetes access such as pods, services etc. when you use your IAM based access to cluster using kubectl commands

Comment: @prasun I see. Thanks for your inputs. 